# Vue router warning

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I am woring on Vue 3 project using composition API. When I reload the page console shows the following warning:

```
In future versions, vue-router support will be removed. Item templating should be used.
```

What does it mean and how can I remove it? Any responses will be highly appreciated!

I searched the solution but cannot find.

Comment: [look at here][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/4411